# MySQL returning multiple rows that does not match search criteria

Tags: mysql, casting, floating-point, comparison, precision

I have MySQL installed locally, running `SELECT VERSION()` returns this value: `5.6.43-84.3`

When I run a query it is returning multiple rows when it should only return 1 row. Let me set it up, it's easier to explain that way.

1. Create a test table:

```
    CREATE TABLE test_table 
    (
        test_val VARCHAR(255)
    )
    ;
```

2. Load 3 values into the table:

```
    INSERT INTO test_table (test_val)
    VALUES 
    ('9671986020630615'),
    ('9671986020630616'),
    ('9671986020630617')
    ;
```

3. Run this query (This query returns 1 row which is expected):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM test_table
    WHERE test_val = '9671986020630615'
    ;
```

4. Run this query (This query returns 3 rows, which it shouldn't):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM test_table
    WHERE test_val = 9671986020630615
    ;
```

Here's what I have observed about this situation:

1. The first query surrounds the value in the `WHERE` clause with single quotes.
2. The second query does not surround the value in the `WHERE` clause with single tics.
3. The column in the test table is defined as `VARCHAR(255)`
4. It makes sense that the first query returns just one row because it's comparing a string from the `WHERE` clause to a string value in the test table (`VARCHAR(255)`)
5. Something is happening when MySQL compares the numerical value in the `WHERE` clause of the second query to the string value in the test table (`VARCHAR(255)`) which is causing MySQL to return 3 rows instead of just 1.

It makes sense that the first query returns the correct result because it is comparing a string to a string.

It also makes a degree of sense that the second query is returning a bad dataset (3 rows as opposed to the 1 row it should return).

But my question is *why* is MySQL doing this? Why when it compares a number to 3 different `VARCHAR(255)` values does it return all 3 rows when the true value of the numerical value in the `WHERE` clause only matches 1 row?

So, in essence for the first query MySQL is saying:

> '9671986020630615' = '9671986020630615',
>
> '9671986020630615' <> '9671986020630616',
>
> '9671986020630615' <> '9671986020630617'

but for the second query it is saying:

> 9671986020630615 = '9671986020630615',
>
> 9671986020630615 = '9671986020630616',
>
> 9671986020630615 = '9671986020630617'

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: My _guess_ is that MySQL is trying to interpret both of them as INT (not BIGINT) and since INT cannot hold those values, they end up being the same value. Using sql fiddle shows selecting `CAST(9671986020630615 AS SIGNED)` and `CAST(test_val AS SIGNED)` both result in `9671986020630616` for all rows in the test table.

Comment: @Uueerdo post that as an answer and i'll give you and upvote. Yeah, no one was around me when I came across this. since I posted this question I have asked some people here at work and that is basically what they said, It has to do with MySQL not supporting numbers past like 10 digits or so when comparing numbers to strings.

Comment: Just go with Jones', it looks like they researched it properly instead of just guessing.

Comment: @Uueerdo , you are a gentleman (or gentlewoman) and a scholar, I appreciate your graciousness. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL handles all numbers internally the same way Javascript does, with [IEEE double-precision floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

When you omit the quotation marks from your long numeric strings, that is you write `9671986020630615` in place of `'9671986020630615 '`, MySQL uses the number. Then, when it runs the `WHERE` part of your query, it silently coerces each column value to a double precision number.

But due to the [machine epsilon -- the limit of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) -- of double precision,  9671986020630615, 9671986020630616, and 9671986020630617 all have the same value. So the WHERE finds all three.

```
CAST(9671986020630615 AS DOUBLE) CAST(9671986020630616 AS DOUBLE) CAST(9671986020630617 AS DOUBLE) 
     9.671986020630616e15             9.671986020630616e15             9.671986020630616e15 |
```

See how all three integers have the same representation as DOUBLE?

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick, accurate and specific answer. Upvoted and accepted as answer.

Comment: This page in the mysql docs talks about exactly this issue:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html